# Android: how to make it no space between 2 button in a horizontal linearlayout

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout, space

I just found I cannot remove the space between 2 buttons even if I set the `layout_marginRight` and `layout_marginLeft` as below. But it make sense if I set the space larger such as 10 dp. 
Any way to solve it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="fill_horizontal" android:layout_margin="0dp">
    <Button android:id="@+id/LocationTitleButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end" 
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Add location" 
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <Button android:textColor="#FF000000" 
                    android:layout_weight="0" 
                    android:id="@+id/AddLocationButton" 
                    android:text="Search" 
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should set layout_width of "0dip" for each button. I hope it helps.

Comment: it doesn't work, i will make the right button disappeared since its weight is 0.

Comment: Is it necessary to set the second button's weight to 0?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Please look at [Bryan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16931939/762585). With my answer both buttons overlap. Bryans answer shows the real size of the buttons.

## Old answer:

Just set the `android:layout_marginRight` of the first button to `"-8dip"` or even more. Than the space between the two buttons will get smaller.

Comment: @Muzammil: Can you give an explanation for your opinion?

Comment: Because in the defaut button theme they have space arround button

Answer (score 33):

Try changing the color of the button, because the default interface of the button which is native to android is actually smaller than it's size, and it's center-fitted to make it look cool.

Change it's background to black or something and you'll see the real size of the button.

```
android:background="#000"
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer. Franziskus' answer is really not a good practice.

Answer (score 3):

You can switch to `RelativeLayout`. There is no spacing in that Layout.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set `android:layout_marginRight="0dip"` and you will have to remove the padding with `android:paddingRight="0dip"` for the other button this has to be changed to the left values. I guess you forgot that every android element has generally a padding added to it by default. This is generally a good idea, but if you want to remove it, this is the way.

Comment: I tried, it does not work for removing the gap between 2 buttons. The padding is for the space inside the button.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get rid of the space if you use TableLayout instead.  And you can set negative values for the margin, if it's still adding some default space between them.

Answer (score 0):

Use    "layout_marginLeft" & "layout_marginRigh" to fill background button

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/create_mail" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bItem"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/email_receive3"
        android:onClick="OnClick"
        android:text="@string/inbox" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/email_trash" />


</LinearLayout>
```